# Filter on map doesn't prevent ArrayIndexOutofBounds in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to read pipe delimited text files and here is the code i have

```
val mySchema = new StructType(Array(
  new StructField("COL1",StringType,true),
  new StructField("COL2",StringType,true),
  new StructField("COL3",StringType,true),
  new StructField("COL4",StringType,true),
  new StructField("COL5",StringType,true),
))

val myRDD = sparkSession
            .sparkContext
            .textFile(myFilePath)
            .map(_.split("[|]"))
            .filter(_.length >= 5)
            .map(r => Row(r(0),r(1),r(2),r(3),r(4)))

val myDF = sparkSession.sqlContext.createDataFrame(myRDD,mySchema)

val myView = myDF.createOrReplaceTempView("MY_VIEW")

val totalRecords = saprkSession.sqlContext.sql("SELECT * FROM MY_VIEW")

val countStr = "Total Records ="+totalRecords.count();
```

And i am getting the following Error in the logs

```
WARN TaskSetManager: Lost task 0.0 in stage 52.0 (TID 2460, executor 2): java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 4
```

As we are filtering the records after Splitting the current row into columns why ArrayIndexOutOfBounds is still being thrown. I am unable to figure this out.

Appreciate any help.

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you just use the Spark CSV library and provide the separator?

Comment: Sure never used that library before. Thanks for the info. Will give it a shot